# What is the meaning of the colon (:) when used in algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to implement an algorithm for converting a rank 3 Toeplitz matrix into a rank 3 Circulant matrix using the algorithm [in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oPG2.png)

However, I am unsure what the use of the colon (:) in the description of the values means.

To pick out a specific line, the author of the paper says that we need to set

$\textbf{c}(1,:,:) = \textbf{G}_{xz}$(1,:,:)

Where the values are the index values of the cells, $\textbf{G}_{xz}(i,j,k)$

From a very naive understanding of this, I would assume this means I need to set $i=1$ always, and then accept any values for $j$ and $k$. However, I am not confident of this assessment as this is my first time seeing an algorithm written this way.

Comment: I think you are right, it means that $\textbf{c}(1,j,k) = \textbf{G}_{xz}(1,j,k)$ for all possible $j,k$

Comment: It's MATLAB notation, basically selects a whole index range.

Comment: @bodil ah thank you very much! I haven't used MATLAB before, so not a surprise I haven't seen this then.

Comment: It is also used in python and probably other languages too.